# ASP.NET Web API Persistent Cookie

Tags: asp.net, security, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST service that a user will authenticate with, that I'm porting from WCF REST services.  With WCF Rest, there were problems when persisting the user with a cookie, and instead I had to use the database and create a ticket system.  Is there support for cookies in Web API where I can create a persistent ticket like I would in MVC or web forms for a user, or do the same problems persist with web API too?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cookies in WebAPI have worked just as I expected (coming from an ASP, webforms, then mvc background).  Although, the api for interacting with cookies is a little wonky.